# In search of the 'tex-decoration:none' issue - whole HTML&CSS code provided

Tags: html, css

My question is rather simple,

`text-decoration:none` - is not working in this example when a user hovers over an `<a>` tag. Where is my mistake?

I have provided the whole project to help you understand what I'm trying to achieve. There is a code snippet below that displays my code with the current problem.

Thanks in advance guys.

```css
* {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue";
  font-size: 22px;
  text-decortion:none!important
}

.container {
  color: #a2abbd;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #21212b;
}

.radio-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  margin: 7% auto;
  height: 504px;
  width: 320px;
  background-color: #2c2c37;
  border-top: 1px solid #f1be81;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  -ms-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 50px 151px -36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 50px 151px -36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
  box-shadow: 0px 50px 151px -36px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

header {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 79px;
  height: 79px;
  background-color: #edae61;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

header a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 60px;
  height: 80px;
}

header .arrow {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

header .arrow img {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

header .on-off {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

header .on-off img {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  margin-right: 7px;
}

section {
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

section ul {
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 11px 23px 0px 23px;
  line-height: 1.364;
}

section ul li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #40404a;
  list-style-type: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section ul li:last-child {
  border: none;
}

section ul li a {
  display: block;
  padding: 18px 0px 14px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  color: #a2abbd;
  text-decoration: none;
}

section ul li a:hover p {
  color: #848b9b;
}

section ul li a p {
  display: inline;
}

section ul li a p strong {
  float: right;
  clear: both;
}

section ul li a p img {
  padding-right: 0.5em;
  padding-bottom: 0.2em;
}

section ul .dribbleFM {
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

section ul .dribbleFM .dribble-anchor {
  position: absolute;
  top: -200px;
  z-index: 1;
}

section ul .dribbleFM .dribble-anchor:target {
  top: 18px;
  margin-bottom: 18px;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -moz-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -ms-transition: all 500ms ease;
  -o-transition: all 500ms ease;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
}

section ul .dribbleFM .dribble-anchor:target + .dribble-button1 {
  display: none;
}

section ul .dribbleFM .dribble-anchor:target ~ .dribble-button2 {
  display: block;
}

section ul .dribbleFM .dribble-anchor .volume {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: relative;
}

section ul .dribbleFM .dribble-anchor .volume a {
  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  pointer-events: auto;
  z-index: 100;
}

section ul .dribbleFM .dribble-anchor .volume .img-main {
  margin-left: 33px;
  margin-right: 33px;
  padding-top: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}

section ul .dribbleFM .dribble-anchor .volume .clickable {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
}

section ul .dribbleFM .dribble-button2 {
  display: none;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 79px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #22222b;
  border-top: 1px solid #4d505c;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 79px;
  cursor: default;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatibile" content="IE-edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="netguru recruitment task">
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="radio-container">
        <header><a href="#" class="arrow"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/id8QV4sap"></a>
          <p>
             
            STATIONS
          </p><a href="#" class="on-off"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/idUebcAVp"></a>
        </header>
        <section>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#"> 
                <p>
                   
                  Putin FM<strong>66,6</strong>
                </p></a></li>
            <li class="dribbleFM">
              <div id="dribble-anchor-on" class="dribble-anchor">
                <div class="volume"><a href="#volume-up" class="clickable"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/exjVsiWzp"></a><a href="#" class="img-main"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/ipxUWXkvp"></a><a href="#volume-down" class="clickable"><img src="https://imageshack.com/i/idsjoKxsp"></a></div>
              </div><a href="#dribble-anchor-on" class="dribble-button1">
                <p>
                   
                  Dribbble FM<strong>101,2</strong>
                </p></a><a href="#dribble-anchor-off" class="dribble-button2">
                <p>
                   
                  Dribbble FM<strong>101,2          </strong>
                </p></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#"> 
                <p>
                   
                  Doge FM<strong>99,4</strong>
                </p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> 
                <p>
                   
                  Ballads FM<strong>87,1</strong>
                </p></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"> 
                <p><img src="http://imageshack.com/a/img661/6406/acyLmg.png">Maximum FM<strong>142,2 </strong></p></a></li>
          </ul>
        </section>
        <footer>
          <p>High quality</p>
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What are you attempting to set text decorations to none on? There are no decorations on its creation, but I assume it is for your `<a>` links on hover, correct?

Comment: yep, thats excatly it :)

Comment: So, @codeRomeos answered your question then right? Don't forget to give him his props.

Comment: Don't worry chief, I know how this works ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By defualt, you have already set the `text-decoration:none` for anchors. But text-decoration is not acting on hover for anchors because you have not specified it for `:hover` state.

For `:hover`, Try this,

```
section ul li a:hover{text-decoration:none}
```

Hope this help.!

Comment: Is this the only way? I mean, do I always have to specify all the pseudo-classes to get the decoration out? Shouldn't there be a way to disable all text-decoration in the DOM whatsoever? I've used `*` selector thinking this should work but nope... Besides, this solution doesn't solve my issue totallt y cause the decoration appears when visited. So I guess you'd say I'll have to add `:visited :focus :active` aswell? But there must be some elegant way to achieve this goal I think..

Comment: to disable all the `text-decoration` from DOM for all anchors, just add `a, a:hover{text-decoration:none}`

Answer (score 0):

The solution already post should work fine. By the way, why are you keeping your styles first and then the bootstrap styles. You should keep your styles next to the bootstrap styles. Otherwise, whatever you will loose the impact of your styles overridden by bootstrap styles.

Comment: Thats interesting, could you provide some simple example please?